# How do I prevent a user from deleting a sub-folder within a sub-folder of a share?

Tags: windows, permissions, network-shares, file-permissions

I have a group(**GroupA**) that needs access to a sub-folder(**FolderA2**) of a sub-folder(**FolderA1**) of share **FolderA**.

Shared folder **FolderA** and sub-folders:

```
 FolderA
  |
  +--FolderA1
     |
     +--FolderA2
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish(Steps 1 and 2 working fine):

1. **FolderA** share restricted to Read only, I don't want users to be able to create folders or files in the root of the **FolderA** share.
2. **GroupA** should be able to create,delete, and modify folders and files in  **FolderA1** folder but not be able to delete the **FolderA1** folder. I have this working fine up to this point.
3. **FolderA2** must only be accessible to a couple of users that also belong to **GroupA** as this folder contains sensitive information that only two users should be authorized to access.

Since I have everything working fine up to step 2 or sub-folder **FolderA1**, I will only describe what I have done for **FolderA2**.

To address **FoderA2** issue, I have done the following:

1. Created **GroupB**
2. Added users  to **GroupB** that need access to **FolderA2**
3. Disabled inheritance to **FolderA2**.
4. Removed **GroupA** access
5. Added **GroupB** access to **FolderA2** security and Applied to "***This folder only***" and selected the following under advanced permissions:

   - Traverse folder/execute file
   - List folder/read data
   - Read attributes
   - Read extended attributes
   - Create files/write data
   - Create folders/append data
   - Write attributes
   - Write extended attributes
   - Delete subfolders and files
   - Read permissions

     6. Added another **GroupB** access to **FolderA2** security and Applied to "***Subfolders and files only"*** and selected the following under advanced permissions:
   - Traverse folder/execute file
   - List folder/read data
   - Read attributes
   - Read extended attributes
   - Create files/write data
   - Create folders/append data
   - Write attributes
   - Write extended attributes
   - Delete subfolders and files
   - Delete
   - Read permissions

After applying this access rights, I tested users that belong to **GroupA** and they are indeed not able to access **FolderA2** which is good. Now I try users that belong to **GroupB** and they can access **FolderA2** as intended but they are also able to delete FolderA2 and that is NO GOOD. They are not supposed to be able to delete that folder. How do i get around this?

NOTE: Just so you know, since the users that need access to **FolderA2** are already members of a group that has access to the share **FolderA** and sub-folder **FolderA1**, I did not add **GroupB** access to **FolderA** share or **FolderA1** sub-folder. I just added **GroupB** access to **FolderA2**.

======The following are the images that show the settings of the folders======

FolderA Share Permission

[image: FolderA Share Permission:]

FolderA Permission Entry:

[image: FolderA Permission Entry:]

Advanced Security Settings FolderA1:

[image]

FolderA1 Permission Entry 1:

[image: FolderA1 Permission Entry 1]

FolderA1 Permission Entry 2:

[image: FolderA1 Permission Entry]

FolderA2 Advanced Security Settings:

[image]

Permission Entry for FolderA2:

[image: Permission Entry 1 for FolderA2]

Permission Entry 2 for FolderA2:

[image]

When testing user access that has access to FolderA2, access is denied:

[image]

If I add "List Folders" a 3rd permission applied to "This folder only", I can access the folder. I can delete files and folders but I can't create files or folders and I am able to delete FolderA2.

Comment: @walmart Here's the update for the folder permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated server. Same issues.

Users and Groups:

**GroupA**

UserA

**GroupB**

UserAB

Thanks for all the help Walmart. It seems that the problem was at **FolderA1**. Here's the pictures of security rights of the folders:

**FolderA** Share Permissions:

[image]

**FolderA** Advanced Security Settings:

[image]

**FolderA** Permission Entries:

[image]

**FolderA1** Advanced Security Settings:

[image]

**FolderA1** Permission Entries:

Entry 1:

[image]

Entry 2:

[image]

**FolderA2** Advanced Security Settings:

[image]

**FolderA2** Permission Entries:

Entry 1:

[image]

Entry 2:

[image]

This works great. Locks out unauthorized users from **FolderA2**.

I am still puzzled with the effective rights for **GroupB** on **FolderA2**, see below:

**GroupB** Effective permissions on **FoderA2**:

[image]

**UserAB** Effective permission on **FolderA2**:

[image]

Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> **They are also able to delete FolderA2 and that is NO GOOD. They are not supposed to be able to delete that folder. How do i get around
>   this?**

You can run the applicable [icacls](https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) commands to the specific and explicit folder you wish to lock down, and `DENY` the `DELETE` permission at that folder level to `GroupB`. So once you get `GroupB` setup with the access you need it as you explain, simply run this command and all should be set as you need it.

**1. Disable Inheritance**

Right-click the `FolderA2`, select `Properties`, <kbd>**`Security`**</kbd> tab,  <kbd>**`Advanced`**</kbd>, <kbd>**`Disable Inheritance`**</kbd>, select the `Convert inherited permissions into explicit permissions on this object` option, and then click <kbd>**`Apply`**</kbd> > <kbd>**`OK`**</kbd>.

[image]

Back in the <kbd>**`Security`**</kbd> tab of `FolderA2` properties, select the <kbd>**`Edit`**</kbd> button. Now select and remove all groups and accounts listed but leave `Domain Admins`, `System`, and `Creator Owner`, `Apply`, `OK`.

Now run the below **iCALCS Command** against the `FolderA2` folder just as shown, then click <kbd>**`Apply`**</kbd> > <kbd>**`OK`**</kbd>.

**2. iCALCS Command**

<sub>*Be sure to look over **Disable Inheritance** and complete that before you run this command*</sub>

```
icacls "\\server\FolderA\FolderA1\FolderA2" /deny "GroupB":(DE)
```

**BONUS NOTE:** *The above also prevents the infamous inadvertent drag and drop of the folder too.*

**WARNING:** *If in a domain environment, please allow up to one hour for security changes become effective. Once security changes do become effective, user accounts may need to logoff and then back onto a computer\system before they'll get the newly setup NTFS ACL security permissions.*

---

### Equivalent GUI Method

**3. Explicit Deny**

Right click on `FolderA2`, select `Properties`, go to the <kbd>**`Security`**</kbd> tab, and select the <kbd>**`Advanced`**</kbd> button. From the `Advanced Security` window, select the <kbd>**`Add`**</kbd> button. Then from the `Permissions Entry` window, click on the `Select a principal` option, and type in `GroupB` and press <kbd>**`Enter`**</kbd>. From here you will select the `Deny` permission in the `Type` field, and select the `This folder only` in the `Applies To` field. Lastly, just ensure that only the `Delete` option is selected in the `Advanced Permissions` window, and press <kbd>**`Apply`**</kbd> > <kbd>**`OK`**</kbd>.

[image]

**4. Explicit Allow**

Be sure that any `MODIFY` permissions you grant or allow `GroupB` to have to `FolderA2` explicitly that you're sure you apply it to `Subfolders and files only` otherwise the `GroupB` may get the ability to delete the `FolderA2` from this configuration explicitly from what I tested.

[image]

---

### Further Resources

- [iCACLS](https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html)

  > - DE - Delete
  > - /deny user:permission
  >
  >   Explicitly deny the specified user access rights.
  >
  >   This will also remove any explicit grant of the
  >
  >   same permissions to the same user.

Comment: Added the deny as you instructed in the GUI method and it does not work. It still allows the GroupB users to delete FolderA2. I tried the ICACLS cmdlet and I get a message: DE : The term 'DE' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,.....

Comment: Here is a snapshot of the permissions as seen from a user that is a member of **GroupB** logged on to windows 7 Enterprise [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qz7226yxct3opxc/win7userloggedin.png?dl=0).

Comment: This snapshot([FolderA2 Permissions](https://www.dropbox.com/s/19ibfce33mbcjuj/FileserverGroupB.png?dl=0)) shows the permission entries for **FolderA2**

Comment: Walmart - User(member or **GroupA** and **GroupB**) effective permission snapshot [User effective permissions](https://www.dropbox.com/s/an3b89bdjji90j8/FS%20effective%20permission.png?dl=0)

Comment: Walmart - This snapshot([GroupB](https://www.dropbox.com/s/trm0q42qmfk8ycd/fs%20group%20effective%20permission.png?dl=0)) shows the effective permissions of **GroupB**.

Comment: Walmart - I don't think I mentioned which server I am using. I am using **Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard** and **Windows 7 Enterprise**.

Comment: Walmart - I tried the new procedure, starting at step 1 and I am unable to access the folder with the user that needs access to it. I believe I tried adding another permission with traverse and I am able to get in but it still allows me to delete that folder. The testing is being done in a virtual environment using virtualbox, running a windows-2012-server(Domain controller), windows-2012 file server, and 2 client windows 7 enterprise guests. Don't know if this may be causing issues. When I get home today, I will post, every setting begining with the share.